# Checking for homomorphism ($\mathbb{Z}_6 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_6$)?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

I'm trying to define a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_6 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_6$.

I've got $f(x)=ax$, $a \in \mathbb{Z}_6$ as a candidate, but how am I supposed to show this as a homomorphism?

Merely (laborously) show that $$f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_6$?

Comment: Group homomorphism or ring?

Comment: @Upstart: The tag says group.

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- but it won't be *that* laborious; you can do it symbolically once and for all.

Take care not to use the letter $a$ both for the parameter of the homomorphism and one of the elements you're checking the homomorphism condition for. And remember that the group operation on both ends of the homomorphism is (modular) *addition* rather than multiplication.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @UmbertoP.: I think it answers the question. Note the last paragraph of the question in which the OP asks whether such-and-such is the way to do it. As that is indeed the way to do it, the answer to his question is "yes".

Comment: How do I/you infer that this concerns addition and not multiplication?

Comment: @mavavilj: You need to know that when someone calls $\mathbb Z_6$ a group, they must be talking about $(\mathbb Z_6,{+})$ -- because $(\mathbb Z_6,{\times})$ is not a group at all; for example $3$ does not have a multiplicative inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Just pick the generator of $Z_6$ say $a$ and try to map it to the elements whose order divides the order of$ a$.
i.e you can map a to elements of order $1,2,3,6$.
So in total you get all of $Z_6.$
$$f(1)=a$$ for all $a$ in $Z_6$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: Why can we pick the generator?

Comment: This is one easy way..and logical way because if you keep on mapping elements randomly you could end up doing an error.but if you map the generator it will itself keep mapping your elements because in the end it is the generator of the group and every element is some multiple of it

Comment: Could you clarify how the $f(1)=a$ works in homomorphic sense? $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$.